# Create a command for a Linux executable file

Tags: path, executable

I'm using a program called node-webkit, but I can't start the program without specifying the full path to the executable file. Is there any way to associate a command (such as `node-webkit`) with an executable file on Linux, so that the full path to the file won't need to be specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A third option, perhaps least intrusive, is to add an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/a/17538/92812) in your `.bashrc` file. This file is a set of options for `bash` which it reads every time an instance of `bash` is started.

- Open your `.bashrc` file with your file editor, for e.g `gedit ~/.bashrc`
- Add the below line to the bottom of your `.bashrc` file
  `alias node-webkit=/path/to/node-webkit`
- Do `source ~/.bashrc` to be able to use the alias as if it were a command.

The way this works is like `#define` in C/C++, when you type `node-webkit`, it will be replaced with the right hand side of the `alias` definition, which here is the full path to the executable.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not always read when bash is executed, it will only be read by a.) interactive shells, and b.) non-login shells. `.bashrc` should be sourced from `.bash_profile` to work around the latter.

Answer (score 10):

In order for the binary to be executed with it's name alone, the directory containing the binary needs to be in one of the directories specified by your `PATH` environment variable. You can add the directory the binary is currently in to your PATH with the following:

```
export PATH="/new/path:$PATH"
```

You can place this in an initialization script for your shell, `~/.bashrc` for example. When it is a single command, I typically symlink the binary to location already in my PATH.

```
ln -s /path/to/node-webkit /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure ... symbolic links. The command is "ln".

```
me@computer:~> echo $PATH
/usr/lib/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/opt/lsb-tet3-lite/bin:/opt/lsb/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
```

This is your path variable. Say, you have root privileges, creating a symlink into /usr/bin makes sense:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /path/to/your/program/node-webkit node-webkit
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. eg - symlink where?

Comment: Any location, which is already within your path. I assumed, you do not want to change your path variable.